# Can the Async REST response from cloud be able to reach premise client that sits behind firewall?

Tags: jax-rs, cloud, reverse-proxy, firewall, java-ee-7

I have an Asynchronous REST cloud-premise scenario here.

I have a webLogic server (with JavaEE7 certification) running on-premise and behind firewall. I have an asynchronous REST client with JAX-RS 2.0 in that server. 
On cloud, we have an Async REST resource that needs to be invoked from premise for GET operation. The aim is to download a 2GB file using async GET mechanism. 
I believe we can make outbound calls from being behind firewall to cloud (through allowed ports) and get data synchronously. Since the response from cloud is async and it reaches premise at a later point of time, can the response pass through firewall while coming back to premise ?

If not, does it need something like DMZ or Reverse Proxy or firewall port-opening (I think it is bad to open port of firewall).. ?

Experts.. please share your views.

Comment: It depends on your actual settings. Http get is often open but I've seen very restrictive setups. Ask your admins

Comment: I'm raising the flag to close this as offtopic as it is too broad

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow and please read up on [what types of questions it is good for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).